# Understanding Java code for Tetris

Tags: java, for-loop, tetris

First off, just so we are completely clear, I took too classes on java a year ago. I have the fundamentals, but am pretty rusty. I tried to code Tetris on my own, but got stuck for a few days so I decided to look up a tutorial. I checked out the "tutorial" at http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/tetris/ but it was hardly a tutorial and more just code. So, in order to help myself better understand it, in hopes of coding my very own Tetris, I took the code, simplified it, changed one or two things, and have sense been writing comments out of what I believe each line does.

I'm just looking for someone to confirm if the code is actually doing what I think it is doing. More specifically with the enum part, the rotate, and the random method. 
Thank you for any of your time, I know I'm biting off more than I can chew, but I have already learned so much by looking up many tutorials and videos and reading through my java book that I don't want to stop now.

here is the code, thank you for any help:

```
package tetris; //keeps things tidy

import java.util.Random;  //needed for when the random shape generator is used
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Shape {

    enum Tetrominoes { NoShape, SShape, ZShape, IShape,     //enum allows to predefine a set of constants and group them together
                       TShape, OShape, LShape, FShape };    //This is also used to positionally search the array later on using the ordinal() function

    private Tetrominoes TetrisShape;                        //variable stores one of our many Tetrominoes at a time, see enum^
    private int IndividualBlockCoordinates[][];             //this array is used to hold the actual coordinates of the Blocks on the board
    private int[][][] ShapeCoordinates;                     //this 3-dimensional array holds pairs of the coordinates of each Tetrominoe if they were centered at (0,0)
                                                            //centering at (0,0) instead of using that as a starting Block is really preference, but allows for bettering 
                                                            //centering of Blocks on the board later
    public Shape()                                          //this is the constructor of the class, it is automatically ran because it is a constructor,
    {                                                       //have your constructor run methods in order to run them without having to call them individually
        IndividualBlockCoordinates = new int[4][2];    //-----------------> this array is used to hold the actual coordinates of the Blocks on the board                                                    
        setShape(Tetrominoes.NoShape);  //------|            each line of the array holds a pair of X and Y coordinates for each block of 
                                        //      |            the tetromino
    }                                   //      |----------------------------->This is THE purpose of the Shape object/class this calls the 
                                        //                                      setShape method, which gets the ShapeCoordinates and BlockCoordinates

    public void setShape(Tetrominoes shape)            //"shape" takes on one of the 8 Tetrominoes 
    {
         ShapeCoordinates = new int[][][] 
                 {
                    { { 0, 0 },  { 0, 0 },   { 0, 0 },   { 0, 0 } }, //NoShape
                    { { 0,-1 },  { 0, 0 },   {-1, 0 },   {-1, 1 } }, //SShape
                    { { 0,-1 },  { 0, 0 },   { 1, 0 },   { 1, 1 } }, //ZShape
                    { { 0,-1 },  { 0, 0 },   { 0, 1 },   { 0, 2 } }, //IShape
                    { {-1, 0 },  { 0, 0 },   { 1, 0 },   { 0, 1 } }, //TShape
                    { { 0, 0 },  { 1, 0 },   { 0, 1 },   { 1, 1 } }, //OShape
                    { {-1,-1 },  { 0,-1 },   { 0, 0 },   { 0, 1 } }, //LShape
                    { { 1,-1 },  { 0,-1 },   { 0, 0 },   { 0, 1 } }  //FShape
                 };
                                                                            //this nested for loop is the money maker right here. With each loop through, it stores 1 value
         for (int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++)                                       //in the IndvidualBlockCorrdinates, therefore, every two loop throughs will provide the x and y value for a singular block
            {                                                               //with 8 total loops, it return the pair of coordinates for each of the 4 blocks in a Tetronimoe
                for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
                    {
                        IndividualBlockCoordinates[i][j] = ShapeCoordinates[shape.ordinal()][i][j];
                    }
            }
         TetrisShape = shape;       //stores one of the 8 tetronimoes in TetrisShape???
    }

    private void setX(int index, int x) 
    { 
        IndividualBlockCoordinates[index][0] = x;    //sets the first element on row (index (0,1,2, or 3)) to x
    }
    private void setY(int index, int y) 
    {  
        IndividualBlockCoordinates[index][1] = y;    //sets the second element on row (index (0,1,2, or 3)) to y
    }
    public int x(int index) 
    { 
        return IndividualBlockCoordinates[index][0]; //returns the first element on row (index (0,1,2, or 3)) to x
    }
    public int y(int index)
    { 
        return IndividualBlockCoordinates[index][1]; //returns the second element on row (index (0,1,2, or 3)) to y
    }
    public Tetrominoes getShape()  
    { 
        return TetrisShape;                         //returns a TetrisShape(one of the 8 tetronimoes) which also holds individual block coordinates
    }

    public void setRandomShape()
    {
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();          //random number generator
        int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(7);     //picks random numbers from 0 to 7
        Tetrominoes[] values = Tetrominoes.values();    //Tetrominoes array name values holds 8 shapes
        setShape(values[randomInt+1]);                  //setShape method is called on one of the 8 shapes represented by values+1, so 1-8 position in enum 
    }                                                   //for example, values[2] retruns enum position 2, or SShape


    public int minY()                                   //returns the lowest Y coordinate of each block
    {
      int m = IndividualBlockCoordinates[0][0];         //initialiezes m, the variable used to find the lowest coordinate to 0,0 in the array
      for (int i=0; i < 3; i++) {
          m = Math.min(m, IndividualBlockCoordinates[i][1]);  //this runs through the first two sets of coordinates and stores the lower of the two
      }                                                       //as m, it only has to check twice because the lowest coordinate of each piece can be
      return m;                                               //found within the first two blocks. m is compared to each of the two, the lowest one is then stored
    }                                                         //as a new m. It will always be 0 or negative 1

    public Shape rotate()                           
    {
        Shape RotatedPiece = new Shape();
        RotatedPiece.TetrisShape = TetrisShape;         //Rotated Tetris Shape now because stored as Tetris Shape
     for(int i=0; i<4; i++)                             
         for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
         {
                RotatedPiece.setX(i, y(i));             //Sets new X value for each piece one by one
                RotatedPiece.setY(i, -x(i));            //Sets new Y value for each piece one by one
         }

     return RotatedPiece;                               //returns the rotated piece with new coordinates
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com, you'd be better off posting there

Comment: @Suseika is right. This isn't really the type of question SO is for. However, yes, your comments on the bits you specifically asked about seem reasonable.

Comment: @Suseika is wrong. Speaking as a Code Review regular, ***explain code is off-topic for Code Review***. That being said, *once you do understand your code*, I think you will find Code Review helpful.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg But topicstarter doesn't ask to explain the code, he clearly states that he is, quote, "looking for someone to confirm if the code is actually doing what I think it is doing". Isn't that what code reviews are about?

Comment: @Suseika The OP did not write this code. On Code Review, the OP should be the one who writes the code. I believe this question goes under "explaining other people's code", which is off-topic. Code Review is about doing the same thing in a cleaner way. Please see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253975/be-careful-when-recommending-code-review-to-askers

Comment: I agree - the OP must have written the code on CR for [multiple reasons](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1294/why-is-only-my-own-written-code-on-topic).

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Okay, I guess you're right.

Comment: Dang, my bad guys, still pretty new to stack, and coding in general. Should i put it on CR? Or would i be better off just continuing on my own?